# Python, Can't Transform Date Array to days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dt, timedelta

I have this csv file "rfm_data.csv":

```
CustomerID PurchaseDate  TransactionAmount ProductInformation
8814       11-04-23             943.31          Product C
2188       11-04-23             463.70          Product A
4608       11-04-23              80.28          Product A
2559       11-04-23             221.29          Product A
```

I read and transform data with this code:

```
    data = pd.read_csv("rfm_data.csv")
    data['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate'],  format='%d-%m-%y')
    data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - data['PurchaseDate'].dt.date).dt.days
```

When I print (data) I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?
```

If I delete the dt.day from the last line of code I got this result:

```
CustomerID PurchaseDate  TransactionAmount ProductInformation Recency
8814       2023-04-11             943.31          Product C   140 days, 0:00:00
2188       2023-04-11             463.70          Product A   140 days, 0:00:00
4608       2023-04-11              80.28          Product A   140 days, 0:00:00
2559       2023-04-11             221.29          Product A   140 days, 0:00:00
```

But what I want in [Recency] is only the number of days to make further calculations.

Comment: shouldn't `format='%y-%m-%d'`?

Comment: Yes you are right, the csv information in the post was incorrect.  It is corrected now....

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now.  I was going crazy, even Bard and Chagpt generated the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in calling `.dt.date`, which returns a vanilla Python date object column - that has no `dt` accessor. Since your input only has dates, normalizing to the date is not needed. If you need to do it anyways (other use case maybe), use `.dt.floor("d")`.

EX:

```bash
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """CustomerID PurchaseDate TransactionAmount ProductInformation
8814 11-04-23 943.31 Product-C
2188 11-04-23 463.70 Product-A
4608 11-04-23 80.28 Product-A
2559 11-04-23 221.29 Product-A"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=" ")
data['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate'],  format='%d-%m-%y')
data['Recency'] = (pd.Timestamp("now").floor("d") - data['PurchaseDate']).dt.days

print(data)
   CustomerID PurchaseDate  TransactionAmount ProductInformation  Recency
0        8814   2023-04-11             943.31          Product-C      140
1        2188   2023-04-11             463.70          Product-A      140
2        4608   2023-04-11              80.28          Product-A      140
3        2559   2023-04-11             221.29          Product-A      140
```

Note that you can also use `pd.Timestamp("now").floor("d")` to get today's date, which makes the code a bit more clean since you use pandas exclusively.